# How to trigger jquery validation on form submit rather than on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using [Jquery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to validate, I am trying to validate all fields on click of submit button. 
But if you see in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4667963x/) by typing wrong email format and if you move to password that next input field it gives message saying "Please enter a valid email address", which I dont want.

I want all fields to validate on click of submit button till then submit button should be disabled when all fields are valid then allow user to click and validate once again to check fields.

is it possible to invoke validaion plugin on submit?
Here is what I tried so far
Html code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" >

    <div class="label">First Name</div><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Last Name</div><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div class="label">Password</div><input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br />
    <div style="margin-left:140px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

  </form>
```

my js code

```
$(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register-form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            agree: "required"
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
$(function() {

onfocusout: false,
onkeyup: false,
onclick: false

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        agree: "required"
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        lastname: "Please enter your last name",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        agree: "Please accept our policy"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    },
     errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
      return true;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        alert(validator.valid());
        //if(validator.valid()) show your modal then use validator.errors() to show custom errors
    }
  });

  });
```

Comment: Actually when the form is valid I want to open another tab so I am asking is there any way to get valid or not? I mean if I click submit form validates and if form is valid then do something like $('tab').addClass('active) else $('tab').addClass('inactive) ??

Answer (score 0):

This simple validation might work for you. Please have a look.

```
$('tab').addClass('inactive);
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){

//Onclick get all the input value
var firstname = $("#firstname").val(),
    lastname = $("#firstname").val(),
    email = $("#email").val(),
    psw = $("#password").val(),
    regx = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/;


//If anything is invallid
if(firstname == "" || lastname == "" || email == "" || !regx.text(email) || psw == ""){

    if(firstname == ""){ //if firstname is blank
        alert("Please enter your first name");
    }
    if(lastname == ""){ //if lastname is blank
        alert("Please enter your last name");
    }
    if(email == ""){ //if email is blank
        alert("Please enter email id");
    }
    if(!regx.text(email)){ //if email is not in proper format
        alert("Please enter valid email id");
    }
    if(psw == ""){ //if password is blank
        alert("Please enter password");
    }

    return false; //form will not submit, it will return false
}else{
    $('.tab').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');  //if for is valid, add/remove class to the element
}

});
```